# How to get a block level element to stick to the bottom of a div (which itself is absolute positioned)?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="sidebar-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.main { 
   position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0; 
     right: 0;
     height: 500px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I need sidebar-footer to align itself to the bottom of sidebar also. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XswfB/)

CSS:

```
.main { 
    border: solid 1px blue;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    border: solid 1px red;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0; 
     right: 0;
     height: 500px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar-footer
{
    border: solid 1px green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

​